# How do I increase a numeric value inside a dictionary which is inside of a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So, I have this code:

```
playersList = []
nome = (input("Informe o nome do(a) jogador(a): "))
playersList.append({"Nome": nome, "Cérebros": 0})
print(playersList)
```

How do I get to increase that 0 value into 1?

Comment: you can index it and then use the key! `players_list[0]["Cérebros"] += 1`

Comment: @ti7: What's `players_list`?

Comment: @littleblackroms: Do you know the index of the dictionary in the list?

Comment: @martineau should be `playersList` from their example

Answer (score 1):

So you have a list called `playerList`, and you added a dictionary with two keys.

To get the first item of the list you can use `playerList[0]`

To change Cérebros you can do `playerList[0]["Cérebros"] += 1`

Comment: Minor nitpick: An array is a block of contiguous memory used to store homogenous data. A list is a collection of pointers. Python's `[]` creates a _list_, not an array.

Comment: Major problem: `Cerebros` is not an _attribute_ of `playerList[0]`, so you can't do `playerList[0].Cerebros`. It's a _key_ in that dictionary, so `playerList[0]["Cérebros"]` is the way to access it

Comment: Your code isn't *increasing the value*, it's hardcoded to set it to `1`.

Comment: Ok added the most needed plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
playersList[0]["Cérebros"] = playersList[0]["Cérebros"] + 1
print(playersList)
```

Output:

```
[{'Nome': 'nome', 'Cérebros': 1}]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.